# How to I print Data in human readable format on a template?

Tags: django

I have data in the following format coming from an API :"2019-05-29"
I want to print it as May 29,2019
Below are the files and the response I am receiving from the API
The response of the API

```
"Data": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "news_title": "Recent Update",
                    "news_description": "This is recent one line description",
                    "image_id": 1,
                    "news_date": "2018-05-18",
                    "news_content": "the big content",
                    "slug": "recent-update",
                    "company_id": 1,
                    "user_id": 1
                }
            ]
```

Views.py:

```
def BlogViews(request,blog_type):
    """
        The blogs are displayed according to the latest, current-month and last-month classification
    """
    blog_type=blog_type.replace('-','_')
    response_blog=requests.get("API" % (settings.BASE_URL,blog_type),headers=headers,verify=False)
    if(response_blog.status_code==200):
        data_blog=response_blog.json()
        if(data_blog['ErrorCode']==0 and data_blog['SubErrorCode']==0):
            blog=BlogYearViews()
            if(len(data_blog['Data'])>0):
                blog_images=BlogImages(data_blog)
                blogs_and_images = zip(data_blog['Data'], blog_images)
                blog_type=blog_type.capitalize()
                blog_type=blog_type.replace('_',' ')
                return render(request,"CombinedBlog.html",{"blogs_and_images": blogs_and_images, "years":blog,"title":blog_type})
            else:
                blog_type=blog_type.capitalize()
                blog_type=blog_type.replace('_',' ')
                return render (request,"NoBlogs.html",{"title":blog_type,"years":blog})
        else:
            return redirect('/404')
```

CombinedBlog.html

```
<h2>{{title}} Articles</h2>
<ul>
{% for blog, image in blogs_and_images %}    
<li><h3>{{ blog.news_title }}</h3><br/>     
    <a href="/blog/article/{{ blog.slug }}"><img src="{{ image.image_name }}"/></a><br/>
    <time>{{blog.news_date}}</time><br/>
    <a href="/blog/article/{{ blog.slug }}">click here</a><br/></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Django Template filter Has [**Date filter**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date) which you need to use.

**Format** - `{{ value|date:"M d, Y" }}`

**Month in caps (May)** - `M`

**date (01-31)** - `d`

**Year in Full (2019)**
 - `Y`

```
<h2>{{title}} Articles</h2>
<ul>
{% for blog, image in blogs_and_images %}    
<li><h3>{{ blog.news_title }}</h3><br/>     
    <a href="/blog/article/{{ blog.slug }}"><img src="{{ image.image_name }}"/></a><br/>
    <time>{{blog.news_date|date:"M d, Y" }}</time><br/>     # <----- use this
    <a href="/blog/article/{{ blog.slug }}">click here</a><br/></li>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The part where date is to be printed remains empty.

Comment: Were you getting date earlier?

Comment: Yes I was getting the data earlier in the format: "2019-09-29"

Comment: what are you trying in template?

Comment: Yes As @exprator said you need to change the string date to date object to use this functionality.

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help.